# Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"", local:“objectname”)

Tags: java, spring, unmarshalling, maven-jaxb2-plugin, jaxb2-maven-plugin

I'm using jaxb2-marshaller to generate classes to communicate with a webservice. Java-classes are generated with use of wsdl files.

I consume some operations without problems, but with one in a specific scenario where the response don't has the namespace on the tag.

For one operation i got the response like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tns="http://www.xxx.xxx/xxxxx" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <outputType>
         <test>1</test>
      </outputType>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And i call it with WebServiceTemplate from springframework

```
public int test(String command) throws Exception {
        InputType input = new InputType();
        input.setCommandName(command);

        ObjectFactory objFactory = new ObjectFactory();
        JAXBElement<InputType> jaxbData = objFactory.createSendRemoteComand(input);

        JAXBElement<OutputType> response = (JAXBElement<OutputType>) getWebServiceTemplate()
            .marshalSendAndReceive(jaxbData);
        return response.getValue().getTest();
    }
```

And i receive the stack error below because the XML "outputType" don't have the namespace like "tns:outputType", i discovery it mocking response in SOAP UI.

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: elemento inesperado (uri:"", local:"outputType").
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:726) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:247) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:242) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:109) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:1131) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
```

Would anyone know a way to deal with the problem?